# Access лог Apache

Tags: apache, apache2, логирование

День добрый. Захожу я значит как-то в access лог и вижу это (IP-адреса на всякий случай заменены на *IP*)

```
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:06:31:20 +1000] "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:07:24:27 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 928 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:07:50:00 +1000] "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:08:23:34 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1294 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:09:19:32 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:10:14:42 +1000] "GET login.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:13:09:41 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1294 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
IP - - [13/Jun/2020:13:33:19 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

IP не знакомые (по сервисам посмотрел, вроде как зарубежные), CGI я не использую (на сервере просто пара страничек html).

Что это может быть?

Моё мнение, что это кто-то балуется сканированием на предмет уязвимости логина, но я не уверен, хотелось бы услышать ответы специалистов (ну или более продвинутых, чем я).

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и предполагалось, боты сканируют пул ip адресов, в который видимо попал адрес моего веб-сервера.

Сканируют для поиска страницы входа (`login.cgi`) и в дальнейшем поиска в ней уязвимости.